# What regex to match all occurrences of css urls?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

i have a css file with a bunch of background image urls:

```
.alert-01 {
  background: url('img/alert-01.jpg') center no-repeat;
}
.alert-02 {
  background: url('img/alert-02.jpg') center no-repeat;
}
.alert-03 {
  background: url('img/alert-03.jpg') center no-repeat;
}
.alert-04 {
  background: url('img/alert-04.jpg') center no-repeat;
}
```

And I'd like to write a regex that would strip out the urls.

So initially i would get:

```
url('img/alert-01.jpg')
url('img/alert-02.jpg')
url('img/alert-03.jpg')
url('img/alert-04.jpg')
```

Which i could then replace bits to turn them into html `<img>` blocks.

I'm fine with the last bit, but my regex skills are a bit rusty.

My latest try was this: `/^url\(.*?g\)$/ig`

Any help?

BTW I was doing this all in javascript, but the language shouldn't affect the regex really.

Thanks in advance!

Also, just to note, i can't guarantee that the files will always be jpg and may be jpeg, png etc. Also that the arguments into background will always be the same. Hence why i want to extract just the url part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
/url\(.*?g'\)/ig
```

Your mistake was including `^` and `$` in the regexp, which anchors it to the beginning and end of the input string. And you forgot to allow for the quote.

Answer (score 13):

Using a tool like [**Regexper**](http://www.regexper.com/) we can see what your regular expression is matching:

[image: Regex Image]

As you can see there are a few problems with this:

1. This assumes "url(" is at the start of the line.
2. This assumes the content ends with "g)", whereas all of your examples end with "g')".
3. This assumes after "g)" is the end of the line.

What we instead need to do is match just `"url(" [any character] ")"`. And we can do that using:

```
/url\(.*?\)/ig
```

[image: Fixed Regex]

Note that I've removed the requirement for the URL ending in "g" in case the image type is `.gif` or any other non-jpg, jpeg or png.

---

Edit: As [Seçkin M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/824495/seckin-m) commented below: *what if we don't want any other url's; such as fonts which have .ttf or .eot? What is the easiest way to define an allowed extensions group?*

For this we can predefine what extensions we're looking for by putting our extensions within brackets, separated with `|`. For instance, if we wanted to match only `gif`, `png`, `jpg` or `jpeg`, we could use:

```
/url\(.*?(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)\'\)/ig
```

[image: Amended Fix]

Comment: Great answer! But what if we don't want any other url's; such as fonts which have .ttf or .eot extensions? What is the easiest way to define an allowed extensions group?

Comment: @SeçkinM. good question! I've modified my answer to include how to handle that. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
/^url\((['"]?)(.*)\1\)$/
```

with jQuery :

```
var bg = $('.my_element').css('background-image'); // or pure js like element.style.backgroundImage
    bg = /^url\((['"]?)(.*)\1\)$/.exec(bg);
    bg = bg ? bg[2] : false;
if(bg) {
// Do something
}
```

*Cross with Chrome / Firefox*

http://jsfiddle.net/KFWWv/

Answer (score 3):

I came to this question from google. Old one, but none of the answer is discussing about **data:image/*** urls. Here is what I found on another google result that will only match http or relative urls.

```
/url\((?!['"]?(?:data):)['"]?([^'"\)]*)['"]?\)/g
```

I hope this would help other people coming from search engines.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex:

```
/\burl\([^)]+\)/gi
```

There's no need to use anchors (`^` and `$`) as they would restrict the match over whole string input and hence fail. To capture the image path separately so that you can use it easily (and avoid substring) when constructing your `<img>` tags use:

```
/\burl\('([^']+)'\)/gi
```

This captures `img/alert-xx.jpg` in group one.

Answer (score 0):

You were just not accounting for the closing quote

```
 url\(.*g\'\)
```

and anchoring