# Javascript regular expression to match css image urls but not data urls

Tags: javascript, css, regex, shopify

I'm using the following javascript regular expression to target image urls in my css and wrap them in a liquid tag (for use in a Shopify theme):

```
text.replace(/url\(()(.+?)\1\)/g, "url({{'$2' | asset_url}})");
```

This will change this:

```
url(example.jpg)
```

to this:

```
url({{'example.jpg' | asset_url}})
```

This works fine, but my css also contains data urls which I don't want to target. e.g.

```
url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2212px%22%20height%3D%2216px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2012%2016%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2012%2016%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cg%3E%20%3Cg%3E%20%20%3Cg%3E%20%20%20%3Cg%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%2300ABA8%22%20points%3D%229.8%2C15.3%2011.1%2C13.7%204.1%2C8%2011.1%2C2.3%209.8%2C0.7%200.9%2C8%20%20%20%20%20%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%3C%2Fg%3E%20%20%3C%2Fg%3E%20%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
```

How would I need to modify my regular expression to exclude data urls like in the example above?

Comment: Liquid is server side. What's the purpose of doing this with JavaScript?

Comment: @Jason I have a workflow in place using sass and grunt that goes something like this:
* Sass processes css file as normal
* Grunt sees that sass has changed and runs 'copy' task
* Copy task gets copy of new css file and runs regex to change image urls
* Copy task saves this amended css file into a separate theme directory ready for uploading to Shopify
* Shopify Manager app then automatically uploads new css file to my online theme
This workflow allows me to have a version of the theme I can see locally (using standard image urls) and a version ready for Shopify (with asset_url tags).

Answer (score 0):

try using this regular exp

```
/url\(.*?(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)\'\)/ig
```

Comment: "Answers without explanation are really common on "I need a regex to do so-and-so" questions because explaining regexes is hard whereas writing them ain't. Sadly, these answers turn Stack Overflow into a regex writing service. –  Matt Coubrough" (on [Answers without explanation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation))

Comment: i have taken from this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518086/what-regex-to-match-all-occurrences-of-css-urls